# Is Presentism or Four Dimensionalism compatible with being a conscious observer?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, consciousness, time, being-and-time

The most striking feature of our experience is the way that it is present simultaneously and persists over short intervals of time.

If we ignore illusionism how might our experience be explained by Presentism or Four dimensionalism?

Presentism is the idea that the universe can be fitted between the ticks of the fastest imaginable clock and there are no things outside of that universe.  Four dimensionalism allows events to extend in time and has a geometry that includes the possibility of observation at the apex of the [light cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_cone) (this is the classical observer in physics). Over to you.

In response to comments:

"Only present things exist" means that existent things  are present now, at an instant.  According to presentism the observer of a ticking clock is present when there is no tick no matter how fast the ticks occur. In presentism everything is present even when there is no motion at all, even of the tiniest parts and there is no other universe of existing things but this static existence. No motion is possible.  Is this compatible with conscious experience?

The classical observer is occasionally described as at the "apex of the [light cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_cone)".  It is the point where light rays converge at a particular moment.  Observations can be related to such a point.  Optics, from the eye to distant galaxies, is generally referred to such an observation point.  The light cone is especially important in Relativity for several reasons.  Anything travelling along the surface of the light cone will measure itself to be no distance from the apex of the cone (as a result of length contraction).  Any clocks on something travelling along the surface of the light cone will show that the journey straight to the apex (observation point) will take no time. From the viewpoint of things on the surface of the light cone they are simultaneously at the apex.

Comment: Presentism is the thesis "Only present things exist." Please explain how you understand this thesis, and how it relates to consciousness. - What is the apex of the light cone?

Comment: The human eye cannot discern a difference of a nanometer, even though we see distances that are many multiples of a nanometer, so why do you suppose it is a problem that we cannot directly experience a nanosecond but instead experience a coarse-grained resolution of temporal intervals?

Comment: So are you supporting four dimensionalism as more compatible with conscious observation?

Comment: both are compatible with a "confused observer"! (the ones are confusing now with eternity, the others confuse truth with shit (slice truth)) how to combine em? (only confused!) Write a book/library!

Answer (score 0):

Presentism is akin to Newton's absolute time [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_space_and_time#Newton):

> According to Newton, absolute time exists independently of any
> perceiver and progresses at a consistent pace throughout the universe.

However, this form of time was relegated as unobservable by Einstein, [Nature, 1937](https://www.nature.com/articles/140963b0).  Physicists have since tried to prove its existence: [Einstein, Relativity and Absolute Simultaneity, 2010](https://ndpr.nd.edu/reviews/einstein-relativity-and-absolute-simultaneity/).  The example from Van Flandern of synchronised GPS satellites is the most relatable illustration, but the general concept may be inapplicable in the gravitational singularities of black holes where current physics is incalculable, limiting its universality.

On the other hand, clock time, ordinary time, is based on the [caesium standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesium_standard), basically the resonant frequency of the caesium atom in local spacetime.  Since the rate of movement depends on local gravity and other effects this is why absolute time is deemed unobservable and therefore non-existent, apparently like unicorns.  (Not everyone agrees though.)

For a handle on 'the now' an observer is required (as McTaggart so expeditiously tried to omit).  However, the temporality of experience requires a phenomenal type of time (not ordinary time).  In phenomenology the starting point is the certainty of the Cartesian subject, the "I am (experiencing)".  In the 18th century Kant called phenomenal time an intuition; in the 20th century Heidegger said it is part of subjectivity.  Human being (as a verb) is temporal from the start; it has its own time horizon: memory past, present, and future intentions.  Each formulated human act or thought happens in a world of time that is *alongside* ordinary clock time, in quite different contexts.  You can read how Heidegger picks up Kant's idea of phenomenal time and packages it into the structure of subjectivity here: [*Kant and the Problem of Metaphysics*, §34](https://archive.org/details/kantproblemofmet00heid/page/194/mode/2up).

When, in experience, one decides and makes an action, then it vaguely coincides with an ordinary clock time.  To make an extreme anti-example, imagine a waking dream.  Really the time in the dream may not remotely be clock time.  The point is, experience of 'the now' happens in phenomenal time.

Re. OP: *"Only present things exist" means that existent things are present now, at an instant.*

This is a good and proper assumption, it just can't be fully supported.  All things present at the same instant is like the synchronised GPS satellites.  They all know when it is 3pm GMT Earth time even though their atomic clocks all say different times because they can compensate.  Taking a Kantian view of how 'things' exist we can take the illustration of a human on Earth, who at 3pm knows the satellites will send a signal, (even though those signals won't reach Earth immediately or even at the same time).  So at 3pm the observer can know that he and the satellites can exist and act simultaneously, as in presentism.  Extending the scenario gets into difficulty with gravitational singularities, being unable to measure time there.  Notionally the observer could extend it but he would be laying a claim to the existence of things he doesn't know anything about, which is the conundrum of the existence of the unobservable in [Nature, 1937](https://www.nature.com/articles/140963b0).

Answer (score 0):

The problem of explaining the conscious experience of the present is made neither more or less difficult by the idea of presentism. There are experimental cameras that can capture trillions of frames per second, fast enough to track the movement of a pulse of light. In principle I could take a video which would show you existing in a succession of tiny moments, each almost indescribably fleeting, entirely in line with the idea of presentism. Where is the problem with that? You are a collection of fundamental particles, the configuration of which evolves over time- very slowly, in comparison with the shutter speed of the fastest camera (the minimum response time of your brain is billions of times longer). If your thoughts are somehow correlated with the configuration of the particles that comprise your brain, and those configuration states exist in a succession of infinitesimal instants, then your thoughts will retain their form over time too. When you take a photograph, the image is effectively an integral over time of all of the interactions caused by incoming photons while the shutter is open. Your visual perception works in a similar way. The intervals between individual photons arriving at your eyeballs in normal circumstances are far shorter than pico seconds. You mind is utterly too slow to register events at that pace- instead you perceive the aggregate effect of trillions of photons over an interval much nearer a second than a microsecond. The point is that while you exist at successive infinitesimally short instants of time, change is cumulative and configurations persist.

Comment: hi, and apologies for before. i do not think this is a safe place for either of us, which is why i left. i definitely think we should talk before either of us do anything. i hope you are goode, and please know ilu <3 ha peace.